# Property does not exist on type using koa parser to read body parameters

Tags: typescript, koa, koa-bodyparser

I'm trying to use `koa-bodyparser` to read post parameters:

```
router.use(koaBody(), async (ctx: Context, next: () => Promise<any>) => {
    if (
     (!ctx.request.body || ctx.request.body.token != adminToken)
    ) {
      ctx.throw(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, 'Authorization failed');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
```

Getting a type error when accessing `ctx.request.body.token`.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I think so, but the answer is burried somewhere in our git history, I don't remember what it was right now... :(